# How to enable Panini keypad to work on emulator as well

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have to create an Android application in which user can type in all Indian languages.
So for this I think to give user an link in my application from where user could download
IME from which he want to type in `EditText`. I think that  it's better to provide user Panini Keypad App link so that user could download his native language IME.(As Panini Keypad is available in all Indian languages.)

But I have to test it in my emulator as well whether it's working or not. But Panini Keypad IME not works on emulator it gives blank boxes.

So please help me how do I type in my emulator as well using Panini keypad(Actually I am not having actual device on which I could test it).

I have successfully install Panini Keypad and also enable it in setting for typing.

Comment: Hey somebody please help me with this, my whole application depends on it.

Comment: In Language and Input setting of emulator I have set Panini Keypad as default keypad. But in Language section I can't choose Hindi language. May be it's not working because Hindi language is not available in emulator. But on real device it's work even if I not changed default language.